# Regresar un char[] desde una función

Tags: c++, c

Hola mi problema es que cuando intento llamar la función "eltexto" para printear en el main, me aparece un error, en lugar de decir Enrique, dice , eh intentado de casi todo pero nada cambia el resultado.

Les dejo un pastebin para que sea más comod ver https://pastebin.com/dC6QqSaG, los errores son linea 9 y 10, linea 23 y de la 54 a la 57, muchas gracias!

```
int main(){

//Declaración funciones
    int entero();
    float flt();
    double dlb();
    char chr();

    char eltexto();
    char a = eltexto();
    //

    printf("  =============================================  \n");
    printf("-=BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DE METODOS Y FUNCIONES=-\n");
    printf("  =============================================  ");
    printf("\n");

//Funcines
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 1 es: %i\n",entero());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 2 es: %.2f\n",flt());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 3 es: %f\n",dlb());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 4 es: %c\n",chr());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 5 es: %s\n",a);

   printf("  \n=============================================  \n");

//Metodos
    enterof();
    flft();
    dlbf();
    chrf();
    strf();

    return 0;
}

//Funciones
int entero(){
    int a = 4;
    return a;
}
float flt(){
    float a = 3.18;
    return a;
}
double dlb(){
    double a = 65.00814;
    return a;
}
char chr(){
    char a = 'A';
    return a;
}
char eltexto(){
    char name[20] = "Enrique";
    return name;
}

//Metodos
void enterof(){
    int a = 4;
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 1 es: %i\n",a);
}
void flft(){
    float a = 3.18;
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 2 es: %f\n",a);
}
void dlbf(){
    double a = 65.00814;
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 3 es: %f\n",a);
}
void chrf(){
    char a = 'A';
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 4 es: %c\n",a);
}
void strf(){
    char a[20] = "Enrique";
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 5 es: %s\n",a);
}
```

Comment: Tal vez estoy equivocado, pero estás declarando un arreglo caracteres y no les envías un indice de lo que debe mostrar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aunque es posible declarar una arreglo de caracterse en C y C++ `char arreglo[n]` (donde n es el tamaño del arreglo) no es posible utilizarlo como valor de retorno al declarar una función por lo que es necesario hacer uso de punteros o apuntadores.

Otro detalle es que deberías declarar el prototipo de la función fuera del main y obviamente antes de que se utilice. El código especifico para esa función quedaría así:

```cpp
char * eltexto(); //Prototipo: la función devuelve un puntero a un char

int main () 
{
    char *a = eltexto(); //Declaracion de una variable tipo apuntador
    printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 5 es: %s\n",a);       
}

// Declaración de la función
char * eltexto ()
{
    char *name = "Enrique";
    return name;
}
```

Salida del programa:

```
El valor de la funcion 5 es: Enrique
```

Comment: Hola, he utilizado tu código para solucionar el problema y ha funcionado de maravilla. Es necesario liberar la memoria asignada en cada función o sólo se hace por el puntero??

Comment: Se libera la memoria en main debido a que en la función se asigno memoria al crear el puntero name, esa memoria persiste al salir de la función por lo que necesita ser liberada. El tema de los punteros tiene que ver un una región de la memoria denominada heap puedes darle una revisada al siguiente link para ahondar mas en el tema https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Manejo_din%C3%A1mico_de_memoria

Comment: Segun tengo entendido, solo es necesario usar `free` cuando se usa `malloc`, `calloc` o `realloc`, por lo que no veo que sea necesario usar `free` en este caso.

Aqui puedes corroborarlo: [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm)

Comment: Es correcto lo que comentas, en este caso al asignar una string literal el compilador se hace cargo  y el usuario no debe liberar la memoria mediante free(). Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes retornar un array desde una función en C. Tienes que crear una asignación en memoria dinámica o pre asignar el array y pasarlo directo a la función. Por ejemplo.

```
char *foo(int count) {
    char *ret = malloc(count);
    if(!ret)
        return NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
        ret[i] = i;

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    char *p = foo(10);
    if(p) {
        // hacer algo con p
        free(p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O la otra opción es:

```
void foo(char *buf, int count) {
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        buf[i] = i;
}

int main() {
    char arr[10] = {0};
    foo(arr, 10);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la infomación!, me ha servido muchisimo!

Answer (score 0):

Como único me compiló fue añadiendo todas las definiciones encima de `main` ya que main no me los reconocía.

Otra cosa que añadí fue el asterisco en la función de **`eltexto()`**:

```
char* eltexto(){
    char name[20] = "Enrique";
    return name;
}
```

Al definirlas arriba de `main` y añadirle el asterisco (un puntero) pero mi recomendación es usar `std::string`

### Código usado:

```
#include <iostream>


//Funciones
int entero(){
    int a = 4;
    return a;
}
float flt(){
    float a = 3.18;
    return a;
}
double dlb(){
    double a = 65.00814;
    return a;
}
char chr(){
    char a = 'A';
    return a;
}
char* eltexto(){
    char name[20] = "Enrique";
    return name;
}

//Metodos
void enterof(){
    int a = 4;
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 1 es: %i\n",a);
}
void flft(){
    float a = 3.18;
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 2 es: %f\n",a);
}
void dlbf(){
    double a = 65.00814;
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 3 es: %f\n",a);
}
void chrf(){
    char a = 'A';
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 4 es: %c\n",a);
}
void strf(){
    char a[20] = "Enrique";
    printf("\nEl valor del metodo 5 es: %s\n",a);
}

int main(){

//Declaración funciones
    int entero();
    float flt();
    double dlb();
    char chr();

    char eltexto();
    char a = eltexto();
    //

    printf("  =============================================  \n");
    printf("-=BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DE METODOS Y FUNCIONES=-\n");
    printf("  =============================================  ");
    printf("\n");

//Funcines
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 1 es: %i\n",entero());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 2 es: %.2f\n",flt());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 3 es: %f\n",dlb());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 4 es: %c\n",chr());
   printf("\nEl valor de la funcion 5 es: %s\n",a);

   printf("  \n=============================================  \n");

//Metodos
    enterof();
    flft();
    dlbf();
    chrf();
    strf();

    return 0;
}
```

### Código compilado:

```
>   =============================================  
> -=BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DE METODOS Y FUNCIONES=-   =============================================  
> 
> El valor de la funcion 1 es: 4
> 
> El valor de la funcion 2 es: 3.18
> 
> El valor de la funcion 3 es: 65.008140
> 
> El valor de la funcion 4 es: A
> 
> El valor de la funcion 5 es: (null)   
> =============================================  
> 
> El valor del metodo 1 es: 4
> 
> El valor del metodo 2 es: 3.180000
> 
> El valor del metodo 3 es: 65.008140
> 
> El valor del metodo 4 es: A
> 
> El valor del metodo 5 es: Enrique
```

### Fuentes

He grabado una fuente en repl.it para que lo pruebes: https://repl.it/LKh4

Comment: Existe un error en la declaración de la variable name dentro de la funcion eltexto() ya que esta retornando el arreglo de caracteres pero al momento de salir de la función esta variable deja de existir por lo que la impresion de la variable "a" dentro del main es (null) y no responde la pregunta correctamente. Checa mi respuesta para ver un ejemplo de como utilizar correctamente los punteros.

Comment: Gracias Xenoxis por la respuesta, pero sí, el error era el retorno en null